# Show that $A^2=0$ is possible but $A^T A=0$ is not possible.

Tags: matrices

Show that $A^2=0$ is possible but $A^T A=0$ is not possible.

It is clearly true when $A=0$ but for other cases I can not step to prove. Actually, I took an example and I saw it is true but I can not prove the general case.

Comment: is $A$ a matrix ? Then surely you can exhibit a simple example for a matrix $A \ne 0$ that satisfies $A^{2} = 0$. For the other, write clearly the coefficient at row $i$ and column $j$.

Comment: Think about what the diagonal entries of $A^\top A$ are (in terms of the columns of $A$).

Comment: Probably you want $A$ to have real coefficient?

Comment: Yes. $A$ is matrix. And I know the diagonal entries is greater than equal to $0$.

Comment: @FuatRay Then recall that $\sum x_i ^2 =0 \Leftrightarrow x_i = 0$ for all $i$

Comment: Is it about a complex matrix or just real ? in the former case it doesn't hold that $\sum x_i ^2 =0 \Leftrightarrow x_i = 0$, e.g. $x_1^2 + x_2^2 = 0 \Longleftarrow x_1 = 1, x_2 = i$.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that :
$$\|A\|^2 = \mathrm{trace} \left(A^{\mathrm{T}} \, A\right)$$
then :
$$A^{\mathrm{T}} A = 0 \iff A = 0$$
but we can have $A^2 = 0$ for a matrix that isn't null.
Example : For :
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
we have $A \neq 0$ and $A^2 = 0$.